# Symfony2 - Separate Subdomain for HTTPS Connections

Tags: php, symfony, acl

How do you specify a different subdomain for secure content: i.e. in the security.yml file I have the following under the `access_control:` section:

```
- { path: ^/Account/Login, access: isAnonymous(), requires_channel: https }
```

That's all fine for my development environment, because I have a self-signed wildcard certificate. In reality in my production environment for this particular website I have an existing SSL certificate that I'd like to use instead of buying another.

So, say my website is http://www.somesite.com/ and the secure stuff needs to be accessed at https://secure.somesite.com/... How do I tell Symfony2 to go to there instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully hostname based routes is a feature that will be available in Symfony 2.2 . Take a look at this [Pull Request](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/3378).

When the time comes you will be able to [force HTTPS for different URLS](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/force_https.html) (as you are doing now), and adding hostname requirements for your routes. Both things combined would let you use a separate subdomain for HTTPS connections.

In the meanwhile, if you cant wait for this feature to come, you can give this [blog article](http://jay-team.blogspot.com.es/2011/09/symfony2-routing-requirement-in.html) a try.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's a great blog article, looks like it is just what I'm after for now. That pull request looks really interesting. I can imagine it'd be useful for if people want to force certain domains to be used for the areas using the firewall... interesting stuff.